# setReadOnly not working

Tags: android, file, sd-card, readonly

I am using `setReadOnly` method to make my app's directory stored on my SD card 'Read-only'. However this method when called is returning 'false' even though I have provided the app with `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest.
Here's my code :

```
    is.close();
    fos.close();
    Decompress d = new Decompress(productDirectory + "/downloadedfile.zip", productDirectory + "/unzipped/");
    d.unzip();
    File zipfile = new File(productDirectory + "/downloadedfile.zip");
    zipfile.delete();
    productDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/zipfiledemo");
    boolean isWriteLocked = productDirectory.setReadOnly();
    Log.v("Writing access locked",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + isWriteLocked);
```

Comment: This may well not be supported on the FAT-type filesystem of the external storage.  Even if you did manage to make a directory read only, any other app could undo that, since there is no concept of file/directory ownership on the sdcard the way there is on the unix-type filesystem which hosts the app's private storage direcotry.

Comment: As of Android 4.4, it seems apps can't change the file permissions on SD card even with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. But `setReadOnly()` works fine for files inside the app's data folder (/data/data/[package name]/)

Answer (score -1):

You should define permission `android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, it means you can create file and delete file on the SDCard.

Comment: No, that is not what android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS does.